# How to set Android Firebase Bookmarked content different for different users?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a [Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.picknpaste.dashboard) in the Play store which I uploaded 3 days ago. I am using Firebase Database for my application. It is based on One words, Idiom Phrase, Preposition, Phrasal verb important for various examination. There is a bookmark option for each words. Everything was fine.More than 30 people installed my app. But unfortunately I made a big mistake in this.Now the problem is when One user bookmarked any word from the list it showing for all the users in the bookmarked section. When one user deleted any word from the bookmark the app deleting the word for all. I am not using any Login option. Please help me how to set the bookmark option different for different users? Here is my bookmark code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,Idioms.BlogViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, Idioms.BlogViewHolder>
                (Blog.class,R.layout.bank_row,Idioms.BlogViewHolder.class,mUserDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(Idioms.BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, int position) {

                final String fav_key=getRef(position).getKey();
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getExample());
viewHolder.setFavourite(fav_key);

                viewHolder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mfavourite=true;
                        databasefavourite.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                 if(mfavourite){

                                     if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Title")){
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Title").removeValue();
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }else {
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Title").setValue(model.getTitle());
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }
                                     if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Description")){
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Description").removeValue();
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }else {
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Description").setValue(model.getDescription());
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }
                                     if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Example")){
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Example").removeValue();
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }else {
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Example").setValue(model.getExample());
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }
                                 }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to provide authentication but in my answer, I will assume you can't or prefer not to.

To get your app working well, take advantage of the firebase push key which is generated randomly and unique each time. When a user favorites the first time, Generate a push key and save it in shared preferences and each favorite will now be stored on the database with the push key. For now, every user is calling the same reference and changing it with the push key is the only way. The existing users will continue to face the problem since the problem is in the android code.

Your app is cool btw

Code. Your favorite action will change to:

```
//check if user has liked
SharedPreferences local = getSharedPreferences("favorite", MODE.PRIVATE);
String link = local.getString("link", null);
if(link != null){
    databasefavourite = databasefavourite.child(link);
}else{
    link = databasefavourite.push().getKey();
    local.edit().putString("link", link).apply();
    databasefavourite = databasefavourite.child(link);
}
//now continue with your code here
databasefavourite.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
```

Note that you should use single listener as value event listener will get fired each time

Comment: Thank you so much Lucem for Your answer. Please can you explain this with some code? I am very new to firebase.

Comment: I don't understand how to implement first part of your code

Comment: @RahulDas this code belongs on the `viewHolder.favourite` click listener. above this line `databasefavourite.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {` what it simply does is save a unique key in shared preferences the first time someone favorites something. Then it will be using that key as the database location for a user. Each user will have a different reference now in the database

Comment: Well, Thank you Lucem. Your code worked perfectly. But there is a problem in the section where I am showing my Bookmarked Content. It is on another page. For your push key it does not recognizing the value in the Bookmarked Page. But If I add `.push()` beside getRef(position) in this line `final String fav_key=getRef(position).getKey();` it is also creating a unique key for each user. But the Problem is In the bookmarked tab it showing each value double or tripple time. Just see this picture.[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tpDdgB7dOS1NwRcpNaRso2FOqpRC3hga/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: And this is the code of my bookmark page. ![https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dzEfYDPElZcEaYBnBGdBRDukUjs2GKiL/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: First, instead of checking if the data exists, just call `removeValue()` there is no error will be thrown. Then note that your `mDatabaseUser` will be changed with the link you are writing to `databasefavourite.child(link);` Lastly, it may be because you are writting twice on the database, check the contents on the database to validate this otherwise if the items appear twice and they are not dublicated on the database, post a new question with the code. I will look at it

Comment: Thank you @Lucem. I just added login feature in the App and arranged the bookmarked data according to user id. But there is another simple problem. Please help me for this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454417/how-to-retrieve-firebase-database-for-specific-user-only]

Comment: @Lucem hello I have similar but different question to asl. I would like to save and show all products or items added by any profile user , yes authenticated users.. It would mean a lot if you can through some light on it?